# Implementing a web server on a microcontroller

Tags: embedded, tcp, atmega, atmega16

I am trying to implement a web server on to a micro controller as a self learning project.I am considering Atmega16 and Atmega88 as primary options.Need to know which will be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

[Like this one?](http://tuxgraphics.org/electronics/200612/article06121.shtml)

There is example using Atmega88.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps obviously the one with the greatest memory resources.  Neither part in your short-list supports Ethernet so neither is particularly suited to network applications; you would need an external Ethernet solution - the controller on that is likley to be more powerful and more expensive than the ATMega16/88 in any case.

You could of course use the UART and PPP or SLIP, but that is rather restrictive.